# Troubles in compiling (iPhone Dev)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I compiled my app and I am having this error- Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

plus I want to notify the user about what he's going to post. I tried this-

```
NSString *someText = textForSharing;
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirm" message:(@"Are you sure you want to post %@ on your facebook wall?", *someText) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

But it gives me- error:Experession result unused and error: Sending 'NSString' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSString *'

What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From where come this syntax?

```
(@"Are you sure you want to post %@ on your facebook wall?", *someText)
```

Try with

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure you want to post %@ on your facebook wall?", someText];
```

Answer (score 1):

First, expression

```
(@"Are you sure you want to post %@ on your facebook wall?", *someText)
```

returns (*sometext) which is of type (NSString)
but format modifier %@ requires a pointer to object ("id" which is basically pointer to an NSObject)

Second, if you use format, you need function/selctor to *parse* this format (`NSLog() or +[NSString stringWithFormat: (NSString*)format]` or c-style `sprintf()`, etc )

Answer (score 0):

Use stringWithFormat, that will solve incompatible type 'NSString *' error.